# Forcing a component to update on change

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

I am trying to get this componentFunction to re-render with the new data field on the state change that occurs changeValue and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```js
class Classname extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "OriginalString",
    };
  }

  changeValue = (newString) => {
    this.setState({ value: newString });
    this.forceUpdate();
  };

  componentFunction = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <component data={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.changeValue("updatedString");
          }}
        >
          Update
        </button>

        <div className="control-section">
          <DashboardLayoutComponent
            id="dashboard_default"
            columns={5}
            cellSpacing={this.cellSpacing}
            allowResizing={false}
            resizeStop={this.onPanelResize.bind(this)}
          >
            <PanelsDirective>
              <PanelDirective
                sizeX={5}
                sizeY={2}
                row={0}
                col={0}
                content={this.componentFunction}
              />
            </PanelsDirective>
          </DashboardLayoutComponent>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Classname />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is a stale enclosure of `this.state.value` in `componentFunction`.

## Solution(s)

From what I can tell, the `content` prop of `PanelDirective` expects anything that returns, or resolves, to valid JSX (`JSX attribute`). A function callback to provide the content, a React component, or JSX literal all work.

1. Callback to reenclose updated state. Convert to a curried function that can enclose the ***current*** state when component is rendered. When attaching the callback you invoke the first function and pass the state value, the returned function is what `PanelDirective` will use when calling for the content value.

   ```
   componentFunction = (data) => () => (
     <div>
       <component data={data} />
     </div>
   );
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <PanelDirective
     sizeX={5}
     sizeY={2}
     row={0}
     col={0}
     content={this.componentFunction(this.state.value)}
   />
   ```
2. React component. Convert `componentFucntion` to a React component and pass.

   ```
   ComponentFunction = ({ data }) => (
     <div>
       <component data={data} />
     </div>
   );
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <PanelDirective
     sizeX={5}
     sizeY={2}
     row={0}
     col={0}
     content={<ComponentFunction data={this.state.value} />}
   />
   ```
3. JSX literal

   ```
   <PanelDirective
     sizeX={5}
     sizeY={2}
     row={0}
     col={0}
     content={
       <div>
         <component data={this.state.value} />
       </div>
     }
   />
   ```

Also, in case it wasn't obvious, you should remove the `this.forceUpdate();` call in the `changeValue` handler. React state updates are sufficient in triggering the component to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass in the value as param for the componentFunction, then each time the status value changed, the current component re-render, the trigger the function to re-render the child component using new state value.

```js
class classname extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: "OriginalString",
        };
    }

    changeValue = (newString) => {
        this.setState({ value: newString });
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    componentFunction = (val) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <component data={val} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => { this.changeValue('updatedString') }}>Update</button>

                <div className="control-section">
                    <DashboardLayoutComponent id="dashboard_default" columns={5} cellSpacing={this.cellSpacing} allowResizing={false} resizeStop={this.onPanelResize.bind(this)} >
                        <PanelsDirective>
                            <PanelDirective sizeX={5} sizeY={2} row={0} col={0} content={this.componentFunction(this.state.value)} />
                        </PanelsDirective>
                    </DashboardLayoutComponent>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```